# Control the gap of pie labels in R?

Tags: r, pie-chart

```
t = table(iris$Species)
pie(t, labels=rownames(t))
```

This draws a simple `pie`. I want that the labels are a little bit more away from the pie. I checked the `par()` docu but I think I don't understand it completly and I missed the option for that.

This question is explicite about R's own `pie()` and not related to any other extern R package.

Comment: See the source code of the pie function (`getAnywhere(pie())` or `F2` in RStudio). The function uses base `text()` function for labelling. Try to change some parameters, such as increasing the factor 1.1 to 1.3 `text(1.1 * P$x, 1.1 * P$y, labels[i], xpd = TRUE, 
           adj = ifelse(P$x < 0, 1, 0), ...)`

Comment: What the hack is that? `ifelse(P$x < 0, 1, 0)`

Comment: It's the x adjustment of the labels. If the x-value in `P$x` is smaller than 0, it will be assigned to `1`, else to `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can really do this with the `pie` function. If you look at `View(pie)` you'll see that the labels are drawn using the `text` function. This means that they are not really axis labels, and that `par` has little effect on them. You could try to do stuff by using the arguments of the text function (i.e. `pos = 2, offset  = 1`) but this will affect all labels in the exact same way and results in warnings. To me it seems that the only way is the stupid way by adding some spaces before/ after labels. ie:

```
t = table(iris$Species)
nms = rownames(t)
# spaces needed after the labels
nms[2] = paste0(nms[2], strrep(' ', 7)) 
# spaces needed before the labels
nms[c(1, 3)] = paste0(strrep(' ', 7), nms[c(1, 3)])
pie(t, labels = nms)
```

If you want to a better solution, you could rewrite the pie function to be a bit more flexible or use a different package.